# また as moreover?

Tags: grammar, written-language

I was trying to read this wikipedia page a little while ago and came across this sentence :

> またその娘であるイラストレーターの藤森玲子はいとこにあたる。

Here is the link for more context, it's at the end of the first paragraph : https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A4%8E%E5%90%8D%E6%9E%97%E6%AA%8E

I am assuming, in this case, that「また」means something like "furthermore" or "in addition to that", but the sentence's syntaxe is puzzling enough to make me lose all confidence in this conjecture. It's also the first time I see something like 「にあたる」.

Here is my attempt at translating it :

> In addition to that, the illustrator Fujimori Akiko is her cousin.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

First, your understanding of 「また」 in this context is correct.

「あたる/当たる」 here means 「相当{そうとう}する」.  In describing a blood relationship:

> 「A は B に + 当たる」 means "***A is someone's B***." with B referring to a brother, uncle, daughter, niece, etc.

(If I may say this, 「当たる」 is a key word in our language with 20 or so different meanings.  I answered a question recently where it meant "to warm oneself".)

Next, your translation attempt is OKish, but it totally neglects the 「その娘{むすめ}である」 part.  What this refers to is only mentioned in the preceding sentence, which is:

> 「イラストレーター、ブックデザイナーの辰巳四郎は叔父。」 ("The illustrator-book-designer Shiro Tatsumi is her uncle.")

"Her" means "Ringo Shiina's" here.

Thus, 「その娘」 means 「叔父、辰巳四郎の娘」.

> 「またその娘であるイラストレーターの藤森玲子はいとこにあたる。」

, therefore, means:

> "Furthermore, the illustrator Reiko Fujimori, who is his daughter, is her cousin."